# Is there are smart method to let this fill less?? If yes how?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a simple method to write these lines of code??

```
if(character == "Orc Lord")
{
    int hp = Character.hp = 100;
    int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
    int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(hp);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
    Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(hpp);
    while (hpp != 0)
    {
        string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

        if(BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
        {
            if (attack == "attack")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                Console.Write(hpp - str);
            }
        }
    }   
    if(hpp == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Instead of write `if(character == "another game character")` on every character fight opportunity I want to write it in less code.

```
if (character == "Human Lord")
{
    int hp = Character.hp = 100;
    int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
    int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;

    Console.WriteLine(hp);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
    Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(hpp);

    while (hpp != 0)
    {
        string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

        if (BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
        {
            if (attack == "attack")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                Console.Write(hpp - str);
            }
        }
    }

    if (hpp == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Just for more text

```
if (character == "Elf Lord")
{
    int hp = Character.hp = 100;
    int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
    int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;

    Console.WriteLine(hp);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
    Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(hpp);

    while (hpp != 0)
    {
        string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

        if (BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
        {
            if (attack == "attack")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                Console.Write(hpp - str);
            }
        }
    }

    if (hpp == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

if (character == "Dog Lord")
{
    int hp = Character.hp = 100;
    int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
    int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(hp);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
    Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(hpp);
    while (hpp != 0)
    {
        string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

        if (BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
        {
            if (attack == "attack")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                Console.Write(hpp - str);
            }
        }
    }
    if (hpp == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

if (character == "Cat Lord")
{
    int hp = Character.hp = 100;
    int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
    int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;

    Console.WriteLine(hp);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
    Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(hpp);

    while (hpp != 0)
    {
        string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

        if (BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
        {
            if (attack == "attack")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                Console.Write(hpp - str);

            }
        }
    }

    if (hpp == 0)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of doing this dynamically, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, there is. Create a type that contains the shared properties. Create multiple instances of this type. Use a lookup or other association method to create / return the appropriate instances. Use this common data in the actual fight.

Comment: BotChar[index] should probably return this type, such that the code can conceptually be a call to `fight(Player, BotChar[index])` or similar.

Comment: @user2864740 so you advice to write 3 times more code somewhere else to reduce amount of code here.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk It's actually **less** code once the common functionality is removed and is **more** scalable.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk Yup, the quick sketch below is *definitely* "3 times more code". It will also allow an Elf Lord to fight a Cat Lord (and vice versa), and a poor Dog Lord won't be forced to fight only other Dog Lords..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start by identifying all the duplication. I've added a comment in front of those lines. With few exceptions, most copy'n'pasted code is duplicated code that can be reduced.

```
        if (character == "Elf Lord")
        {
            int hp = Character.hp = 100;     // this is written "oddly"
            int str = Character.MaxHit = 20;
            int hpp = Character.hpElf = 100;
            // Console.WriteLine(hp);
            // Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 0);
            // Console.Write("Robot: " + BotChar[BotIndex]);
            // Console.SetCursorPosition(90, 2);
            // Console.WriteLine(hpp);
            // while (hpp != 0)
            // {
                // string attack = Functionality.Select(new string[] { "attack" });

                // if (BotChar[BotIndex] == "Dog Lord")
                // {
                //    if (attack == "attack")
                //    {
                //        Console.SetCursorPosition(108, 0);
                //        Console.Write(hpp - str);
                //    }
                // }
            // } 
            // if (hpp == 0)
            // {
            //    Environment.Exit(0);
            // }
        }
```

So, the "non duplicate" code that currently exists is that a different character (presumably) has different stats. Let's start by categorizing the *common* features:

```
class Stats {
    string Name { get; set; }
    int MaxHp { get; set; }
    int Strength { get; set; }
    int CurrentHp { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's imagine there is only a single character and bot to fight to start:

```
var elfLord = new Stats { Name = "Elf Lord", MaxHp = 100, Strength = 10 };
var dogLord = new Stats { Name = "Dog Lord", MaxHp = 50, Strength = 4 };
```

And they fight:

```
Fight(elfLord, dogLord);
```

Then all all *repetitive and duplicated* code can move to a method:

```
void Fight(Stats f1, Stats f2) {
    Console.WritLine(f1.Name + " vs. " + f2.Name);
    // Do whatever calculations, ONLY using the two parameters supplied.
    // In the called case, f1.Name == "Elf Lord" (given from caller),
    // and f2.Name == "Dog Lord" given (given from caller)
    // (Assuming full-heals at the start..)
    f1.CurrentHp = f1.MaxHp;
    f2.CurrentHp = f2.MaxHp;
    int turnsLeft = 10;

    // Use >= as check on != 0 will loop forever on OVERDAMAGE
    while (f1.CurrentHp > 0 && f2.CurrentHp > 0 && turnsLeft-- > 0) { 
      // Pseudo code showing how this can get complex, yet remain in little chunks, handling a small part of the task.
      // Perhaps the order of f1/f2 is reversed each round based on an initiative roll..
      // ..but just as in a more complex game, rules can be broken down.
      // And the best part is, NO COPY AND PASTE TO MAINTAIN/FIX THIS CODE!
      // "mX" = Move Order. These are also Stats objects and thus effectively aliases.
      // For a 3+ battle system, movements should be handled as a collection.
      Stats m1, m2;
      if (InitiativeSuccess(f1, f2)) {
        m1 = f1; m2 = f2;
      } else {
        m1 = f2; m2 = f1;
      }

      var m1Attack = GetAttack(GetRandomAttack(), m1, m2);
      var m2Attack = GetAttack(m1Attack /* allow counter */, m2, m1);
      ApplyAttack(m1Attack, m1, m2);
      ApplyAttack(m2Attack, m2, m1);
    }

    if (f1.CurrentHp <= 0 && f2.CurrentHp <= 0) {
      Console.WritLine("Mutual defeat.");
    } else if (f1.CurrentHp <= 0) {
      Console.WriteLine(f1.Name + " defeated.");
    } else if (f2.CurrentHp <= 0) {
      Console.WriteLine(f2.Name + " defeated.");
    } else { // draw (no more turns)
      Console.WriteLine("Both fighters give up.")
    }
}
```

Now, the non-duplicated code can be moved out, and it might look something like this:

```
// One of many approaches, a simple switch here would also suffice.
// Methods break up logic and unify (reduce duplication of) code.
Stats CreateLordFromName(string lordName) {
  var elfLord = new Stats { Name = "Elf Lord", MaxHp = 100, Strength = 10 };
  var catLord = new Stats { Name = "Meowth Lord", MaxHp = 9, Strength = 999 };
  var namesToLords = new [] { elfLord, catLord }.ToDictionary(v => v.Name, v => v);
  return namesToLords[lordName];
}

Stats hero = CreateLordFromName(character);
Stats bot = CreateLordFromName(BotChar[BotIndex]);

Fight(hero, bot);
```

It becomes slightly more interesting when adding interactions between different entities. However, it's an extension of above: categorizing the similarities.

Additional similarities might be the attacks a character has. Consider how this is really an extension of the same. As the complexity of the domain increases, new types and categorization might be useful.

```
var slash = new SlashAttack(); // class SlashAttack : IAttack
var stab = new StabAttack();   // class StabAttack : IAttack

var hero = new Character {
    Stats = ..,
    Attacks = new [] { slash, stab } // IAttack[] array/collection
};

var catLord = new Character {
    Stats = ..,
    Attacks = new [] { meow, hiss, loveLicks }
};

Fight(hero, ..);
```

For an interesting interaction, consider that there might also be a "Pet" attack that would work against a "Cat Lord" causing a Cat Nap (+1 HP, sleep for one round). There are multiple ways of continuing the model above to support such.. and such is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: It comes with a lot of errors when i put paste code in.

Comment: It's a *gist* / *example* / *suggestion* / *guidance* to show how to reduce duplicated commonality, not a complete program. Any minor bugs are as this answer: free.

Comment: Digression: Avoid a copy'n'paste from this site. Read the code and surrounding information as presented, take the relevant constructs, and re-write / build from the constructs as relevant. During this process it should be very clear the code above is absolutely *not* a complete/valid program as presented, while allowing one to follow similar approaches to adapt the current code.

Comment: Well in that case. Thank you for help